# CNContactViewController ignores allowsActions

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller

`CNContactViewController` ignores `allowsActions`. SMS and Mail actions are offered:

[image]

with `contactVC.allowsActions = false`.

---

I setup CNContactViewController in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
...
let newContact = CNMutableContact()
newContact.emailAddresses.append(CNLabeledValue(label: CNLabelHome, value: "me@me.com" as NSString))
contactVC = CNContactViewController(forUnknownContact: newContact)
guard let contactVC = contactVC else {
    return
}
contactVC.contactStore = CNContactStore()
contactVC.delegate = self
contactVC.allowsActions = false
...
```

Why does CNContactViewController show actions with `contactVC.allowsActions = false`?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic button bar is not controlled by this setting. (Some have commented elsewhere they were added after iOS 9, when this framework was added).

This setting controls the label-style buttons that appear at the bottom of the sheet.

***in iOS 11***

Enabled:

- FaceTime row (after phone number, not available in simulator)
- Send Message
- Share Contact
- Share My Location

Everything else is the same.

Checked with initializers "for:" and "forUnknownContact:"

No idea for previous versions, I started in iOS 11...

[image: allowsActions = false]

[image: allowsActions = true]

Comment: Thanks. Not a very satisfying answer, but that's on Apple. No change with iOS 13.3.

Comment: @How did you get those buttons to be grayed out? I mean the Message, Call, FaceTime, and Mail buttons?

Comment: My observation is that these buttons are parsing the contact data. So in my example, because the contact is essentially empty, they are all dark.

The smartness of the buttons has varied over time. Early on, I noticed that a phone number might activate different buttons based on whether the number is registered in iMessage (blue bubbles!) or simply a valid phone number (SMS/MMS assumed). 

This is a pretty complex area, I haven't bothered to try to sort it out in detail.

Answer (score -1):

The AllowsActions property does nothing for me too. My best guess is that Apple forgot to support the property when they updated that view controller in newer versions of iOS (it looks quite a bit different now than it did in iOS 9 when the Contacts framework was first released).  If anyone has figured out a way to make it work, or to hide that UI, please share.

Comment: Determines whether to display buttons for actions such as sending a text message or initiating a FaceTime call. Maybe that's what they mean

Comment: Yeah, that is what is supposed to do (Apple comments in the SDK are very good), but it simply doesn't work anymore since Apple redesign of the Contacts details view and placed the action buttons above the contact properties.  Now I don't know of any way to hide the action buttons.

Comment: (it would be better to *not* refer to them as action buttons, action buttons are clearly the label-style buttons across the bottom, and the setting still controls their behavior in iOS13... there's a whole set of behavior for the new things, best discussed in detail elsewhere)